# Java - Char Buffer Issue

Tags: java

I have a character file of 1.99 GB. Now, I want to extract millions of sub-sequences from that file randomly for example from position 90 to 190, 10 to 110, 50000 to 50100 etc. (each of 100 characters long).

I usually do it using,

```
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file , "r").getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
    Charset chars = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    CharBuffer cbuf = chars.decode(buffer);
    String sub = cbuf.subSequence(0, 100).toString();

    System.out.println(sub);
```

But, for 1.99 gb file above code gives error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:328)
        at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:792)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:791)
```

So, I used following code,

```
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file , "r").getChannel();
CharBuffer cbuf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()).asCharBuffer() ;
String sub = cbuf.subSequence(0, 100).toString();

System.out.println(sub);
```

which does not gives above error but returns output:

```
ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹ä¹
```

Which should be "011111000000........"

Can anybody help me why this things happening and how to solve it ?

Comment: Based on docs "IllegalArgumentException - If the capacity is a negative integer". May be try by explicitly setting capacity using allocate()?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html

Comment: @thinksteep, I explicitly set it to 2 billion, gives IllegalArgumentException exception.

Comment: What is the RAM allocated for JVM -Xmx settings?

Comment: First test with only 1K byte mapping, instead of the entire channel size. If it does not work, then your issue is not memory. Something else.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing, but I think `Charset.decode(ByteBuffer)` fails when it tries to allocate a *huge* `CharBuffer` for you behind the scenes. Again, this is just a hunch, but the `decode` method only decodes bytes from the buffer's current position up to its limit, so you can do something like this.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ...
Charset charset = ...

buffer.position(0);
buffer.limit(100);

System.out.println(charset.decode(buffer));
```

The capacity (in characters) of the `CharBuffer` returned by the `decode` method will be 100.

<sub>(On a side note, I think your second attempt gives erroneous output, because you didn't use a particular character set to decode your `CharBuffer`.)</sub>